# Is this series limited to six numbers only?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Maybe this problem is already answered. I am not aware.

What is the next number in the following series?

Importantly, after that number, are there any more numbers? Is there a math-related reason for that?

> 1, 512, 4913, 5832, 17576, ?

Comment: A simple online search for **1, 512, 4913, 5832, 17576,** yields the answer. See the following: https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211GB0G0&p=1%2C+512%2C+4913%2C+5832%2C+17576%2C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe these are the numbers known as:

> **[Dudeney numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudeney_number#Dudeney_numbers,_roots,_and_cycles_of_Fp,b_for_specific_p_and_b)** - in particular, *the sequence of base-10 **natural** numbers* (hence no 0) *whose digits sum to the number's cube root*.

Like so:

> 1 (trivially)
>  512 = **8** cubed and digit sum 5+1+2=**8**
>  4913 = **17** cubed and digit sum 4+9+1+3=**17**
>  5832 = **18** cubed and digit sum 5+8+3+2=**18**
>  17576 = **26** cubed and digit sum 1+7+5+7+6=**26**

The next number in the sequence is:

> **19683** which both is **27 cubed** and **has digit sum 27**.

Moreover:

> These have been demonstrated to be the only six numbers to possess this property in base-10. See the linked Wiki page for a discussion - I will leave any further exposition of the mathematics to another puzzler who has the stamina to engage in a MathJax marathon!

Comment: I think that zero should be added as well?

Comment: There is a 7th number, 0 (which of course comes before the 1 and is usually left out because it's trivial)

Comment: @BennettBernardoni ninja'd :)

Comment: Lol, by 4 seconds. So close

Comment: @LeppyR64 (and Bennett!) That's true - I should specify we're talking natural numbers only. Thanks...